# How to obtain good framerate using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, web-worker

I'm trying to apply filters to full-hd videos in javascript using pixel manipulation.

I created a demo using hidden canvases, web workers and transferables:

http://lab.jure.it/ww/ww.html

The result is that using web workers the browser's tab crashes in a short time, and the video has very low performances (~5fps).

If you select "Web workers: 0" ww are not used, the performance is better (~15fps) and the tab doesn't crash.

What can i do about it? The goal is to obtain a good framerate (~30fps) avoiding SVG or CSS filters.

Thanks.

Comment: Do the pixel manipulation on smaller images, or use at maximum globalCompositeOperation instead of pixel manipulation. Not knowing what effects you want, it's hard to help you much more.

Comment: The demo uses grayscale, but the "filters" should be anything, e.g. blur, chroma key, rgb channel regulation, watermarking, and everything you can do manipulating pixels.

Comment: @Killy You need to narrow your problem down. You can't really expect anyone to dig through your project and benchmark your performance. But anyway, I strongly recommend that you use WebGL. PixiJS framework has nice demos showing filters with high FPS: http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/15/indexAll.html

Comment: Grayscale can be done with gCO, blur can be done with drawImage, chroma key should be done on smaller images, rgb channel => gCO. And browsers start to natively support [ctx.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter)

Comment: Oh and if all you want is to display the filtered video, there is also the CSS filter possibilty, applicable directly on the video element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping through all pixels and converting them on CPU is not a good idea. That's what GPUs are for. In past, that would mean you have to use something nasty, like Flash.

Fortunately, new technologies are emerging and graphic acceleration is available in most popular browsers. It's called WebGL and it allows you to make use of graphic card for these things.

Unless you want to learn all the internal secrets of WebGL (it's quite complicated), I advise you to use PixiJS framework, which is designed for 2D animation.

You can see their filtering demo here: http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/15/indexAll.html

More demos and examples are here: https://pixijs.github.io/examples/#/basics/basic.js

Comment: thank you all,  i mark this as the solution but your comments are all useful :)

Comment: Canvas2d API does transfer to GPU too. The one thing to avoid is the getImageData/putImageData

Comment: @Kaiido Well, it's quite irrelevant how is static image handled (GPU/CPU). What we need here is some sort of animation.

Comment: My point is that all compositing operations are handled by the gpu, drawImage is handled by the gpu, and filter when supported is handled by the gpu. The ones that aren't are getImageData and putImageData. And even there, you can be smart enough to perform pixel manipulations on downscaled frames and then use gCO to apply it on the normal scaled one.

Comment: And I may not have got your static image reference. OP is filtering a video (a set of static images? ) and if I'm not wrong, since I know little about webGL, It means that he would have to create a new texture every frame. Not sure the creation of the texture is performed on GPU.

Comment: @Kaiido No it's not, but sullying a texture vs converting every pixel of image makes a great difference, trust me.